# jQuery UI Multiselect Next - onChange - remove all, add all

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select

I have jQuery UI Multiselect Next http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_next I want to fire an event whenever the selection changes in any way.

This example works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
$("#countries").multiselect();          
$('#countries').multiselect({ selected: function(event, ui) {change(); } });
$('#countries').multiselect({ deselected: function(event, ui) {change(); } });
});         

function change(){
alert('CHANGE');
}

</script>
```

When I move an element from a list, the function change() is called.
The main problem is when I press "Remove all" or "Add all", because the function is called many times (the number of elements).

Is possible call the function change() **only one time**, when I press "Remove all" or "Add all"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

Open ui.multiselect.js

Add following line to selectAll function:

`this.element.trigger('change');`

Add following line to selectNone function {

`this.element.trigger('change');`

Add following line to stop function

`that.element.trigger('change');`

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){       
        $("#countries").multiselect();          
        $('#countries').bind('change', function() {alert('Change'); });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure. but you try [jquery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

Comment: Yes i find [Solution See this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/GDuRn/1/). Please tell me is right or not.

Comment: There are too many bugs.
Try to drag and drop or press the buttons add / remove repeatedly.

Comment: sorry boss, you r wrong i will test i think you wrong check link.

Comment: this bug in `multiselect` bug but i will solve your problem. plugins not my problem.

Comment: I need call the function multiselect_change(); every time that I move the items or press the buttons, but only 1 time for movement or click. In your example http://jsfiddle.net/GDuRn/1/ when the input value=1 the function is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of timing scheme to filter out the extra calls. Let's assume for a minute that a real human being is not going to be able to trigger the selected or deselected event more than once every 100 milliseconds. You could do the following:

```
var lastChange = 0;

function change() {

  //get current date, then the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970
  var curr_date = new Date();
  var n = cur_date.getTime();

  //compute the difference.
  var diff = n - lastChange;

  //update our last change variable.
  lastChange = n;

  //if we're within 100 milliseconds of the last call, ignore.
  if (diff < 100)
     return;

  //proceed as normal.
  alert('change!');
}
```

You could tweak such an algorithm to meet your needs, I am using 100 milliseconds as an example. I'm not sure there's a cleaner way of doing this since you're basically trying to filter events coming from the UI control itself.

Comment: With your function, when I press "remove all" the function is called 2 times not one: http://jsfiddle.net/GDuRn/

Comment: sounds like an async issue. You might need to add a semaphore to keep it from running twice. Again, not a pretty solution, but it might do the trick.

Comment: Found a related stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185910/prevent-javascript-from-being-executed-twice