# Stop spamming a button

Tags: javascript, slider, intervals

How can I implement in js that whenever I press a button that the function gets executed once and then waits a couple of seconds so the user has to wait. I would like to implement this because if I spam the button the actions get executed too fast. The setInterval etc is not what I want because it simply waits a couple of seconds but thereafter you will get bombed with alert message's for instance. So an interval on a function but thereafter it needs to be executed once.

I hope that I have explained this clearly,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185910/prevent-javascript-from-being-executed-twice?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth - Apparently "click spamming" is a thing - see http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Click+spamming

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose is but have you considered that when the  button is clicked you then disable it.

Comment: Yes I did and that is not what I want. Try the code below from phgrey it is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTimeout instead of setInterval - that will fire the function to run only once

Or even better - in the event listener save the last clicked time in the global variable. something like:

```
var last_clicked = 0;
button.onclick = function(){
  if (Date.now() - last_clicked < 10000) return;
  last_clicked = Date.now();
  // Here You should put the listener code
}
```

Comment: Men, thanks you are a genius I am new to js, I am a C sharp game and application development, so web is very new to me ;)